# Angular: Difference between subscribing to output event in view vs component in Push-Mode

Tags: angular

I have a parent component and a child component. The parent component is marked with OnPush change detection strategy. The child component triggers an output event after a timeout via setTimeout.
If I subscribe from the parent component to the output event inside the view, the change detection for the parent component is triggered. However, if I subscribe to the event inside the parent component class, the change detection is not triggered. The number doesn't get updated in the view. Don't know why Angular makes here a difference.

child component:

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() clicked = new EventEmitter<number>();

  number = 1;

  ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.clicked.emit(123);
    }, 3000);
  }

  ngDoCheck() {
    console.log('ChildComponent doCheck');
  }
}
```

parent component with subscribe in view (change detection works):

```
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  number = 0;

  onClicked(newNumber: number) {
    console.log('onClicked', newNumber);
    this.number = newNumber;
  }

  ngDoCheck() {
    console.log('ParentComponent doCheck');
  }
}

<app-child (clicked)="onClicked($event)"></app-child>
Number: {{ number }}
```

parent component with subscribe in component (change detection does not works):

```
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('child') child!: ChildComponent;

  number = 0;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.child.clicked.subscribe((newNumber) => {
      console.log('onClicked subscribe', newNumber);
      this.number = newNumber;
    });
  }

  ngDoCheck() {
    console.log('ParentComponent doCheck');
  }
}

<app-child #child></app-child>
Number: {{ number }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I try and avoid playing with change detection so much as I can, so I'm not entirely certain of the answer.

That said, my guess would be that going through the view (`(click)="onChildClick($event)"`) makes the request go through the framework and thus you hit all the relevant hooks and so you get your change detection.

Subscribing makes the output go directly to jail without passing go, so it doesn't trigger any framework hooks necessary.

Either leave it view-based as God intended, or hit `ngDoCheck()` in your subscription yourself.